# Jquery UI Sortable - Disallow to Drag at Bottom

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a problem with the `sortable` function in jQuery. 
I would like to disallow the "footer" on a Table-List from dragging out.
Other elements can drag to the last position and are then the new footer.

How can I disallow this?

Here is my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/afaxpems/2/

I know the solution with `tfoot`, but I have already a `tfoot`. And the row should in `tbody` because my other jQuery Script parse it and send via ajax the inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/afaxpems/4/)

Use :

```
  items: 'tr:not(:last-child)',
```

Instead of

```
   items: 'tr:not(.not-sortable)',
```

Comment: I ask me, why I didn't try this. I believed that this option dont solve my problem. Thanks for it.